# Is there an R fuction to repeat same code but filter for specific objects

Tags: r, dplyr, repeat

So this is the code I'm working with:

```
TE1<- transposons %>% select("Chromosome", "Annotator", "Repeat_class.superfamily", "Start", "End") %>% filter(Chromosome == "I") %>% arrange(Start)
```

I need to repeat this code five more times but filter for a different chromosome at each repeat. As a result there should be five tables named: TE1, TE2, TE3, TE4 and TE5. Within eacht table the right data for eacht chromosome.

Is it possible to make this happen with one line of code? I've tried to put this in a for-loop but couldn't make it happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `assign` in a `for` loop, changing the chromosome for each interation.

```
chromosomes = c("I", "A", "K", "C", "D") #The values of the 5 chromosomes

for(i in 1:5){
  assign(paste0("TE",i),
         transposons %>% select("Chromosome", "Annotator", "Repeat_class.superfamily", "Start", "End") %>% filter(Chromosome == chromosomes[i]) %>% arrange(Start))}
```

I'd recommend to add those tables to a list, instead of creating a new variable to each:

```
new.list = list()
for(i in 1:5){
   new.list[[paste0("TE",i)]] = transposons %>% select("Chromosome", "Annotator", "Repeat_class.superfamily", "Start", "End") %>% filter(Chromosome == chromosomes[i]) %>% arrange(Start))}
```

Comment: The (named) list is almost always the way to go. If somebody *really* wants it back in the environment, can always use `list2env()`!